# Override default Model View

Tags: flask-admin

How can I override the Model View so by default all Model Views have exact same settings which I override?

For example:
I have 5 model views linked to some db models which are all custom,but I want all these 5 to have some default settings so I won't have to write code for each view in the ModelView class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance:

```
class BaseView(ModelView):
    #  Add common functionality here
    pass

class ProductView(BaseView):
    #  Add specific functionality here
    pass

class CategoryView(BaseView):
    #  Add specific functionality here
    pass
```

A simple one file example below.

Class `BaseView` turns on `can_view_details` and formats the `description` column in upper case.

Notice the difference between `ProductView`, which inherits from `BaseView`, and `ProductNotInheritedView` which inherits directly from `ModelView`.

Note the code uses the [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to generate random data.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from faker import Faker
from flask_admin import Admin

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create in-memory database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


class Supplier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'supplier'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.UnicodeText(), nullable=True)

    products = db.relationship("Product", back_populates="supplier")

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.Unicode(32), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.UnicodeText(), nullable=True)

    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('supplier.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
    supplier = db.relationship(Supplier, back_populates='products')

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class BaseView(ModelView):
    can_view_details = True

    column_formatters = {
        'description': lambda v, c, m, p: m.description.upper(),
    }


class SupplierView(BaseView):
    column_list = ('name', 'description', 'products')


class ProductView(BaseView):
    pass


class ProductNotInheritedView(ModelView):
    pass


admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(SupplierView(Supplier, db.session))
admin.add_view(ProductView(Product, db.session))
admin.add_view(
    ProductNotInheritedView(Product, db.session, name='Product Not Inherited', endpoint='product-not-inherited'))


@app.before_first_request
def build_sample_db():

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    fake = Faker()

    _suppliers = []
    for _ in range(20):
        _supplier = Supplier(
            name=fake.company(),
            description=fake.paragraph(nb_sentences=fake.random.randint(1, 10))
        )
        _suppliers.append(_supplier)
        for _ in range(fake.random.randint(1, 10)):
            _supplier.products.append(
                Product(
                    name=' '.join(fake.words(nb=fake.random.randint(1, 5))),
                    description=fake.paragraph(nb_sentences=fake.random.randint(1, 10)),
                    code=fake.isbn10(separator="-")
                )
            )

    db.session.add_all(_suppliers)

    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: * admin.add_view(MyModelViewIntrari(Intrari, db.session, 'Intrari'))
* class BaseView(ModelView):
* class MyModelViewIntrari(BaseView): And the error; Attempted to instantiate admin view MyModelViewIntrari without default view

Comment: @titpoettt - I've added a simple one file example.